# How to update textarea with replace method through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xml

I have a textarea that will contains a code entered by user and I want to get that code and scan it with jQuery to get the value inside a custom tag called setting then add this value to an input so the user will be able to change the value inside setting tag without touching the code. I was able to get the values and add them inside the inputs but I couldn't update the code with the new values.

HTML CODE :

```
<div id='tab-1'>
  <textarea id='template-code' cols='67' rows='27'></textarea>
  <button id='submit-code'>Submit Code</button>
</div>

<div id='tab-2' class='unactive'>
  <form id='settings-form' method='POST'>
    <div id='result'></div>
    <button id='update-code'>Update Code</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS CODE :

```
.unactive {
    display: none
}
```

jQuery CODE :

```
$('#template-code').change(function (){

  var $that = $(this),
      template_code = $that.val(),
      code = '',
      new_data = '',
      text = '',
      newCode = '';

  // Extract settings from the theme and add them to #result              
  $(document).on('click', '#submit-code', function (){

      $('#tab-1').addClass('unactive');
      $('#tab-2').removeClass('unactive');

      $(template_code).find('setting').each(function (i){

        var $this = $(this),
            setting_std = $this.text(),
            setting_id = $this.attr('id');

        code += '<input id="'+setting_id+'" name="'+setting_id+'" type="text" value="'+setting_std+'"><br>';

      });

      if(code !== ''){
        $('#result').html(code);
      }

  });

  // Update old data with the new one
  $(document).on('click', '#update-code', function (){

    new_data = $( "#settings-form" ).serializeArray();
    $.each( new_data, function( i, new_field ) {

        var start_key = "id='"+new_field.name+"'>",
            end_key = '</setting>',
            start  = template_code.indexOf(start_key), 
            end = template_code.indexOf(end_key);

        text = template_code.substring(start + start_key.length, end);

        // THE PROBLEM IS HERE
        // I want the variable template_code to contains the new value not the old one so I used replace but it seems that it doesn't work
        template_code.replace(text, new_field.value);


    });

    $('#template-code').val(template_code);
    $('#tab-1').removeClass('unactive');

    return false;

  });

});
```

This is an example of the theme code that will be added inside the textarea :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html b:version='2' class='v2' expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
  <head>

    <b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>

    <title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>

    <div id='option-panel' style='display:none!important'>

      <setting id='post_thumbnail'>http://lorempixel.com/640/300/</setting>
      <setting id='search_icon'>on</setting>

    </div>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

To understand my issue please enter to this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zo3hh2ye/1/) and copy the code above then put it inside the textarea and click submit code, you will get two inputs the content of those inputs come from these two tags :

```
<setting id='post_thumbnail'>http://lorempixel.com/640/300/</setting>
<setting id='search_icon'>on</setting>
```

I want when the user change the value of inputs and click "update code" to change the value of setting tag inside the entire code.

Comment: Are you're saying you want to pipe entire html pages into a textarea element, or did you mean the data in the textarea be replaced with the textual representation of your template?

Comment: @spynix Actually it is an XML template and I want to replace the value inside setting tag with the new values entered in the inputs by user.
The main idea from this is to let user change the content of setting tag without touching the code. BTW the code will be used in different place this is just a UI to update values.

Comment: Conceptually, are you simply trying to tie together the input of whatever the HTML generated in those fields, back to the value in the code?  If so, I think all you need is index() and val() logic with some conditions applied.

Comment: @AlexanderDixon Yes this is what I want. Can you help me that because I'm a beginner and I get confused quickly. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another version of the code. I saved the new values in an array and then replaced them with the existing values in the textarea text. Give a try and see if that solves your problem.

**Script :**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#template-code').change(function () {

        var $that = $(this),
            template_code = $that.val(),
            code = '',
            new_data = '',
            text = '',
            newCode = '';

        // Extract settings from the theme and add them to #result              
        $('#submit-code').click(function () {

            $('#tab-1').addClass('unactive');
            $('#tab-2').removeClass('unactive');

            $(template_code).find('setting').each(function (i) {

                var $this = $(this),
                    setting_std = $this.text(),
                    setting_id = $this.attr('id');

                code += '<input id="' + setting_id + '" name="' + setting_id + '" type="text" value="' + setting_std + '"><br>';

            });

            if (code !== '') {
                $('#result').html(code);
            }

        });

        // Update old data with the new one
        $('#update-code').click(function () {

            new_data = $("#settings-form").serializeArray();

            $(template_code).find('setting').each(function (i) {
                template_code = template_code.replace("<setting", "").replace("id='" + $(this).attr("id") + "'>", "").replace($(this).html(), "{" + i + "}").replace("</setting>", "");
            });

            $.each(new_data, function (i, new_field) {
                    template_code = template_code.replace("{" + i + "}", "<setting id='" + new_field.name + "'>" + new_field.value + "</setting>");
            });

            $('#template-code').val(template_code);
            $('#tab-1').removeClass('unactive');

            return false;

        });

    });
</script>
```

**HTML Template :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html b:version='2' class='v2' expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
  <head>

    <b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>

    <title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>

    <div id='option-panel' style='display:none!important'>

      <setting id='post_thumbnail'>text1</setting>
      <setting id='search_icon'>text2</setting>

    </div>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I couldn't replace the text 'on' in the template you provided, not sure if it has something to do with some reserved key word but everything else works fine.

Comment: There is a problem in your method which is if I had the text more than one time it change the wrong one. Ex : 

`<setting id='post_text1'>text1</setting>`

When the code will change it will become like this :

`<setting id='post_changed'>text1</setting>`

Comment: Sure. Glad I could help.

Comment: Could you explain line by line how you acheived this, with particular emphasis on the `new_data` and `{i}` methodologies please?

Comment: Also Dino, where there is definitely an issue with the "on" word, could you possibly tweak your code to convert the data input to a string and then update the code?  I think if the data is a string, it will behave better.

Answer (score 2):

Try this and see if it's what you're looking for:

**HTML**

```
<div id='tab-1'>
  <textarea id='template' cols='67' rows='27'></textarea>
  <button id='submit'>Submit Code</button>
</div>

<div id='tab-2'>
  <form id='settings-form' method='POST'>
    <div id='result'></div>
    <button id='update'>Update Code</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function wrap(data) {
  var string = '';
  var i, l;

  string += "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\r\n";
  string += "<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n";
  string += "<html b:version='2' class='v2' expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>\r\n";
  string += "  <head>\r\n";
  string += "    <b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>\r\n";
  string += "    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>\r\n";
  string += "    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>\r\n";
  string += "    <link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>\r\n";
  string += "    <title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>\r\n";
  string += "  </head>\r\n";
  string += "  <body>\r\n";
  string += "    <div id='option-panel' style='display:none!important'>\r\n";

  for (i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++)
    string += "      " + data[i].toString() + "\r\n";

  string += "    </div>\r\n";
  string += "  </body>\r\n";
  string += "</html>\r\n";

  return string;
}

$("#submit").on('click', function() {
  var virtual = document.createElement("div");
  var temp = '';

  virtual.innerHTML = $("#template").val();

  $(virtual).find('setting').each(function(i) {
    var $this = $(this),
            setting_std = $this.text(),
            setting_id = $this.attr('id');

    temp += '<input id="' + setting_id + '" name="' + setting_id + '" type="text" value="' + setting_std + '"><br>';
  });

  if (temp !== '')
    $('#result').html(temp);
});

$("#update").on('click', function(event) {
  var temp = [];

  event.preventDefault();

  $("#result").find("input").each(function() {
    temp.push("<setting id=\"" + this.id.toString() + "\">" + this.value.toString() + "</setting>");
  });

  $("#template").val(wrap(temp));
});
```

I believe that does what you're looking for?  Even though you're using jQuery, I think you ended up making it a lot harder than it had to be.  I used a virtual node to quickly/easily find and pull ONLY the setting tag from the `textarea` on submit (down and dirty, I suppose?).

I removed the styles and whatnot since it was interfering with rapid testing, and you'll need to apply proper sanity checking/validation against user input.

**Edit:** Updated answer to include a ghetto wrapping function to elucidate the concept.  I would not recommend using it as is, but instead utilizing a real template, which would require work outside the scope of this question.

Most recent JSFiddle after editing: http://jsfiddle.net/zo3hh2ye/6/

Comment: This is what I want but instead of removing the entire code and replace it I want to change the code inside #option-panel only and keep other codes. Thanks

Comment: You can wrap the result however you want, via template or otherwise.  You simply need to pipe your variables into your template/wrapping function.  I'll add a simple example in a few minutes.

Comment: Okay brother thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate that.

Comment: Added a wrapping example.  It's a jackassy method, and I suggest using actual templates, but this should give you the general idea.

Comment: Also, I got caught up in the functionality and lost track of the main topic of doing it with .replace(), so Dino's answer is more on point.  And... your template example has divs inside the head tag.  Just saying...

Comment: Yes you are right but Dino's answer is has a problem as I mentioned in the comment on his answer.